# Looping through more than one lists - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to loop over more than two lists simultaneously. I have googled and found that `zip, map` can be used. But they accept only two lists. I wanted to loop over 5 lists.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get that `zip` only accepts two lists? `a=[1,2,3]; list(zip(a,a,a,a,a))` gives `[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3, 3)]`

Comment: But I have tried in the loop `for (item, name, address) in zip(gpxd_wpt_coordinates, gpxd_wpt_names, addressListAll):` here gpxd_wpt_coordinates, gpxd_wpt_names and addressListAll are the lists. I am getting the output for item and name. But i am getting an error that "addredd is not defined"

Comment: I'm guessing `addredd` is a typo? Either way, it looks like it should work just fine. See Jay's answer below that does basically what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry, here I typed manually. But the actual error shows "address is not defined" only

Comment: Sounds like it may be unrelated to zip. Could you add the code that fails to the question?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson.. Thanks for your time. I have figured out. there was a typo in the previous steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what Joachim Isaksson said is correct.

It would be helpful if you can provide a code snippet but you can use something like this:

```
import itertools
for a, b, c in itertools.izip (list1, list2, list3):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) can be used for arbitrarily many lists. I just did this and it works fine.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [10, 20, 30, 40]
l3 = [100, 200, 300, 400]
l4 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]


for x1, x2, x3, x4 in zip(l1, l2, l3, l4):
    print(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

Outputs:

```
1 10 100 1000
2 20 200 2000
3 30 300 3000
4 40 400 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [signature for zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip). It accepts any number of iterables:

> zip(*iterables)

There is no problem `zip`ing multiple lists:

```
a, b, c = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]

for (i,j,k) in zip(a,b,c):
    print(i,j,k)
```

prints:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

You can even zip `0` or `1` iterables!

```
list(zip())          # []
list(zip([1,2,3]))   # [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```